# LocalNotification display on UIcollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uicollectionview

I would like to set a LocalNotification then able to display on a UICollectionView.
However, I only know how to make it display on UITable. What should i do in order to convert it from UITable into UIcollectionview? I would like the UIcollectionview to display the UIlabel with the time and date while i have background image at the back.

Here is my code for building UITable with local Notification.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of notifications
    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Get list of local notifications
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Display notification info
    [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? The API for a collection view is very similar to that for a table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table view and a collection view both use cells to display content.  Once you have a collection view, the two operations you've shown here (determining the number of rows and populating the text for a row's cell) would be the same for a collection view.

Follow a tutorial to get a collection view working, and then look at numberOfItemsInSection and cellForItemAtIndexPath: and compare them to the methods you have above - you should be able to use the code from tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: verbatim, and the code for the other method with only minor changes.